# PHP How to get the timestamp of a server in unix?

Tags: php, mysql, unix

Hello there :) I am basically trying to pull data from a MySQL table, and with it I need the PHP to get the current time on the server as well. So E.G. if it is currently 16-12-2015 and 20:50:36, i need this time to then be converted to unix (which is done with strtotime()).

My question is, how do I get the time of the server in unix put into a $variable?

Thank you,

Joshua

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$variable = time();
```

should do what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are mentioning MySQL, do you want to know how to add this to your query? That would be done like this:

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP() AS timestamp ...
```